# Prove that $na_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence of positive terms such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges.
> Prove that $na_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

$\underline{Attempt}$

By Cauchy criterion for series we have

$\forall \space \varepsilon>0 \space \exists \space N(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $|a_{n}+a_{n+1}+...+a_{2n}|< \varepsilon/2$ whenever $m=2n> n-1>N(\varepsilon)$

and $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n=0$  .

Since $a_n$ is decreasing and positive  $$na_{2n}<a_{n}+a_{n+1}+...+a_{2n}<|a_{n}+a_{n+1}+...+a_{2n}|< \varepsilon/2$$

$$ 2na_{2n}<\varepsilon 
 \space \space\text{whenever n}>N(\varepsilon)+1 $$ that is $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2na_{2n}=0$
therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} na_{n}=0$.

I am not sure whether my attempt is correct or not Can anyone verify my answer?

$\underline{Edit}$

In the same way $m=2n+1>n+1>N(\varepsilon)$  We have $$2na_{2n+1}<\varepsilon 
     \space \space \text{whenever}\space  n>N(\varepsilon)-1>0 $$

That is $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2na_{2n+1}=0$, and we have  $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+1}=0$. so we have

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (2n+1)a_{2n+1}=0$.

therefore by case one and two  $\lim_{n \to \infty} na_{n}=0$.

Comment: In showing $2na_{2n}\to0$, you've shown that $ma_m\to0$ when $m$ is *even*. You need an additional argument to show that $ma_m\to0$ when $m$ is odd.

Comment: Provide some justification for saying that $2na_{2n} \to 0$ implies $na_n \to 0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra I edited it now? Can you check?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited it now? Can you check?

Comment: @puka, yes, it looks OK now. A possibly simper alternative would be to note that $(2n+1)a_{2n+1}\le(2n+1)a_{2n}$, with $2na_{2n}$ and $a_{2n}$ both limiting to $0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra I think you are saying that $\lim (2n+1)a_{2n+1} \leq 0$ and since $a_n>0, \lim (2n+1)a_{2n+1} =0$ is it correct?

Comment: @puka, yes. Technically you needed to say the same thing in your proof(s). It's a nuance that's often omitted, but probably shouldn't be, when dealing with sequences of non-negative terms.

Comment: @BarryCipra thank you very much